# 2 Filters to Delete in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Hello I am new in CI,

How I can put 2 filters to delete using funtions of codeigniter?

I have this

```
$this->db->where('id_casa', $id_casa); 
$this->db->delete("casas");
```

can I do this?

```
$this->db->where('id_casa', $id_casa);
$this->db->and('id_usuario', $id_usuario);  
$this->db->delete("casas");
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: use $this->db->where(array('id_casa' => $id_casa,'id_usuario'=>$id_usuario););
 $this->db->delete("casas");

Comment: thanks friend !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use

```
  //Associative array method:

 $this->db->where(array('id_casa' => $id_casa,'id_usuario'=>$id_usuario));
 $this->db->delete("casas");
```

(or) If you use multiple function calls they will be chained together with AND between them:

```
  $this->db->where('id_casa' => $id_casa);
  $this->db->where('id_usuario'=>$id_usuario);
  $this->db->delete("casas");


  //both produce : where id_casa=$id_casa and id_usuario=$id_usuario
```

Comment: if its useful mark it with green ticks its useful for future user @siemensgti

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array for the conditions to give in where clause

```
$condition = array('id_casa' => $id_casa,'id_usuario'=>$id_usuario);
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->delete("casas");
```

Comment: Multiple where clauses don't look good if you have more parameters for where condition. Using an array to pass as many parameters for the where clause as you want is a better solution.